# swift swreveal - showing toggling to side menu using button or tap gesture

Tags: iphone, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to get my side menu (swreveal) to show when clicking a `UIImageView` with a tap gesture or button. I've got the image view and tap all set up and the tap gesture linked to an action. Getting this functionality is easy when using a bar button item but I can't seem to get it to function when using a plain old button or image view.

Here's how I do it for a bar button item:

```
barButtonItem!.target = self.revealViewController()

barButtonItem!.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
```

This obviously doesn't work for buttons or `ImageViews` because they don't have a member of `target` or `action`. Would really appreciate some assistance on this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add target to `UIButton` you can use this:

```
...
let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(self, action: "someAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
...
func someAction(sender: UIButton!) {
   ...
}
```

For adding action to press on `UIImageView` you can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` like this:

```
...
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("someAction"))
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
image.userInteractionEnabled = true
image.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
...
func someAction() {
    ...
}
```